# Convert BBCode [link='www.example.com]example[/link] into HTML <a href="www.example.com">example</a>

Tags: php, regex, replace, text-parsing, bbcode

I have a problem with my RegEx. I want to translate a BBCode link tag like:
`[link=www.stackoverflow.com]Stack-Overflow[/link]`

into a HTML link:
`<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>Stack-Overflow</a>`.

In my string it's possible to make more than one link in BBCode.
I also need a function to translate the HTML back to BBCode.

My functions are:

- BBCode To HTML:

  ```
  $Text = preg_replace(
      '/\[link=([^ ]+).*\](.*)\[\/link\]/',
      '<a href="$1">$2</a>',
      $Text
  );
  ```
- HTML To BBCode:

  ```
  $Text = preg_replace(
      '/\<a href="([^ ]+).*\">(.*)\<\/a\>/Usi',
      '[link=$1]$2[/link]',
      $Text
  );
  ```

My problem with these functions is when I have more than one link to convert, it doesn't work.

And when I have one link translated to HTML and I want to translate back, I have only the first character of the link.

Comment: Please note: http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for your first problem, `*` is greedy, so it catches everything between the first and last links. A simple solution is to use a non-greedy qualifier, or to not allow `[]` in your groups:

```
\[link=([^ \[\]]+)\]([^\[\]]*)\[\/link\]
```

Similarly, for the other way around:

```
<a href="([^ "]+)">([^<]*?)\<\/a\>
```

Here's the non-greedy version. It allows `[]` in links, and is even shorter:

```
\[link=([^ ]*?)\](.*?)\[\/link\]
```

Comment: Using the non-greedy qualifier is good enough, and would allow [] in the link, since that may happen. E.g. example.com/?arr[]=1&arr[]=2

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the greedy .*
Use ? to make it non greedy.

```
$Text = preg_replace(
    '/\[link=([^ ]+).*?\](.*?)\[\/link\]/',
    '<a href="$1">$2</a>',
    $Text
);
```

Comment: it has to be inside the parens, otherwise it does something completely different.